# How to check if multiple objects is not nothing VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to check for **not nothingness** in 2 objects and cant' find the right way to write it down.

what I am acutally trying:

```
Dim NArange As Range, NAMERange As Range
Set NArange = Rows(DateRange.Row).Find("#N/A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set NAMERange = Rows(DateRange.Row).Find("#NAME?", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)


If (Not NArange Or Not NAMERange) Is Nothing Then
    debug.print "nothing"
End If
```

how do I write the

```
If (Not NArange Or Not NAMERange) Is Nothing Then
```

condition?

thanks!

Comment: if ((not range1 is nothing) or (not range2 is nothing)) then

Comment: Your condition is incorrect as well. If you want to check whether any of the two objects is "Nothing", then you don't need to put the "Not" keyword. It will check for the condition "Object1 is Not Nothing"  => "Object1 is something".

Comment: @Nvj yes that was unclear, I was looking for **Not Nothingness**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate the two nothing statements like this:

```
Dim NArange As Range, NAMERange As Range

Set NArange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
Set NAMERange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")


If NArange Is Nothing Or NAMERange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("nothing")
Else
    MsgBox ("something")
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to test against nothing first, then combine the results of those comparisons:

```
If NArange Is Nothing And NAMERange Is Nothing Then
```

If you try to apply operators other than `Is` to objects, it will attempt to use the default property instead (in this case `Value`). So, `Not NArange` is equivalent to `Not NArange.Value`.  If `NArange` is `Nothing` you'll get a run-time error 91 - "Object variable or With block variable not set".